# Qt Sending data from mainwindow to secondary window

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

In my main window, I create a 2d QVector of a custom widget called PieceButton. I now want to access the 2d QVector from a different window called puzzle. I am having trouble connecting the 2 forms for data transfer. I create the puzzle I am using before the 2d QVector is filled, but everything I've looked at for this says the connect statement goes inside the constructor for the puzzle(second window), meaning the vector would need to be ready before the puzzle is created.

I also tried putting the connect function into a new function to be called inside main window, but the data still did not transfer so I put it back into the constructor; but is that the better way to do it?

mainwindow.cpp

```
QVector<QVector<PieceButton*>> tilesVec;
...
void MainWindow::on_solveButton_clicked(){
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    x = 0;
    QVector<PieceButton*> row;

    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        ...
        PieceButton *piece = new PieceButton(myPuzzle);
        ...
        row.push_back(piece);
    }
    tilesVec.push_back(row);
}
myPuzzle->show();
emit sendTileData(tilesVec);
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "puzzle.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
signals:
    void sendTileData(QVector<QVector<PieceButton*>> tilesVec);

private slots:
    void on_solveButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Puzzle *myPuzzle;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

puzzle.cpp

```
QVector<QVector<PieceButton*>> tiles;

Puzzle::Puzzle(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Puzzle)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("Puzzle");
    resize(QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry(this).size() * 0.7);

    MainWindow *main;
    connect(main, SIGNAL(sendTileData(QVector<QVector<PieceButton*>>)), 
        this, SLOT(getTileData(QVector<QVector<PieceButton*>>)));

    int count = tiles.count();
    qDebug("%d", count); //this should be greater than 0, but is 0
}

Puzzle::~Puzzle()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Puzzle::getTileData(QVector<QVector<PieceButton*>> sentTilesVec)
{
    tiles = sentTilesVec;
}
```

puzzle.h

```
namespace Ui {
class Puzzle;
}

class Puzzle : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Puzzle(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Puzzle();
    void connecting();
public slots:
    void getTileData(QVector<QVector<PieceButton*>> tilesVec);

private slots:
    void testSlot();


private:
    Ui::Puzzle *ui;
};
```

I have tried to include only the relevant parts of the code for you. The issue lies in the connect statement in puzzle.cpp, but I'm lost as to how to address it. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't matter when you call `connect`. Do this wherever you have both objects in hand for the first time.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so simple... thanks! That worked.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Care to post an answer? OP: Please don't edit something like *"Solved"* into your answer. Usually, you should accept the answer you find most useful by clicking the check-mark next to it instead. This would properly mark the question as solved on a system level. Unfortunately, the question was answered only in the comments so far, which breaks this mechanism. Let's see if that gets fixed.